# Solder station grounding setup

Tags: ground, grounding, esd, soldering-iron-station, setup

I have a Sugon T26 soldering station.

It has an European 2 pin plug, I have a 3 pin adapter for it.

As far as I am aware there will be no ground connection using this method.

It comes with a ground connector on the station, crocodile clip style.

Where should I connect the clip? (I am situated at home.)

I have no access to a ground other than in the wall socket.

Am I better off trying to source a 3 cable wire for the power supply and fixing a standard UK plug to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solder station designed to use in industry. They usually have ground separate from power ground, which is for safety.  For home use you may replace power cable with 3 wire  and grounding pin  and connect green wire to chassy.  The iron body should be grounded. That crocodile style connector for antistatic rug and bracelet.